# Как правильно задать структуру секции

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="container">
       <div class="row">
          <img src="images/car1.png" class="img-responsive col-md-6 car_1" alt=""> 
          <div class="table col-md-6">
             <div class="cell-left col-md-4">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                   <li>Combustibil:</li>
                   <li>Capacitatea cilindrică:</li>
                </ul>
             </div>
             <div class="cell-right col-md-6">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                   <li><i class="fa fa-caret-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;3,0 L</i></li>
                   <li><i class="fa fa-caret-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;automată</i></li>
                </ul>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Как только не пытался сделать, на больших смотрится нормально, только стоит посмотреть на девайсах и все плавает. Это последний вариант, но и с ним не получается. Может кто то подскажет как лучше структуру записать ? (верстаю бутстрапом)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Создай в контейнере 2 блока. Левый с описанием и фиксированной шириной. И правый с картинкой с width: 100%; и относительной шириной например 50%. Таким образом при уменьшении экрана картинка будет уменьшатся вместе с правым блоком, а описание будет оставаться фиксированной ширины. Как вариант.